# Vim: persistent search buffer between vim instances (in Ubuntu)

Tags: search, vim, buffer, clipboard

I have two separate instances of Vim running. I would like to set up my system so that when I search for `something` in one Vim (using `/`, `?`, `*` or `#`), then press `n` or `N` in the other Vim, it searches for the same `something` in the second Vim. I am running Ubuntu.

I already make use of the primary system clipboard for things yanked in vim by using `set clipboard=unnamed` in my .vimrc file.

**Research so far**
The command-line tool "xsel" lets me access three different clipboards in Ubuntu: the *primary* clipboard (used when you select text and middle-click to paste), the *clipboard* clipboard (used for Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V etc.), and the *secondary* clipboard (which seems to be unused). My thought at the moment for Vim to use xsel to set the secondary clipboard when `/`, `?`, `*` or `#` are used, and use xsel to access the same clipboard when `n` or `N` are pressed.

Comment: Sounds like a good question for either Super User or Ubuntu SE.

Comment: Falls clearly under "software tools commonly used by programmers."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was going to just post the code I cobbled together for this here, but then decided to bundle it up into a tiny plugin: https://github.com/dahu/VimSharedSearch

Comment: Using your plugin (v0.0.2), searching with `/` or `?` doesn't seem to save the search until I move the cursor. So if I search using `/`, then press `n`, it will search for the wrong thing.

Comment: Yes, I used the CursorHold event to call SaveSearch(). But... I don't get that behaviour. Searching is exclusive, so it always forces the cursor to move... (provided a match occurs). Can you provide a small sample to recreate the problem my end?

Comment: Ah. You're correct, I only get this behaviour if I search for something that isn't found in the window. Also, a minor annoyance that I'm sure I can get used to is that if I search backwards (with `?` or `#`), then press `n` it searches forwards whereas Vim would normally search backwards.

Comment: Oops! I hadn't noticed the ugly [Nn] problem... Version 0.0.3 tries to fix that, but it's only local to the current Vim session at this stage - meaning, [nN] now work as expected within the current Vim, but alternate Vims will remember their previous search direction. This may not improve - not without saving the search direction in the /tmp/ file too, which just feels wrong. Enjoy. :)

Answer (score 1):

With `clipboard=unnamed` set, you can copy between the last-pattern register (the last thing you searched for), and the shared clipboard using `let @/=@*` and `let @*=@/` (`*` is the clipboard, and `/` is last-pattern).

So you can then create a function that copies the last-pattern into the clipboard and map to `/`, `?`, `*` or `#`, and another which copies the clipboard to the last-pattern for `n` or `N`.

Comment: That's handy to know, but I actually don't want this shared last-pattern register to interfere with the shared clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you were asking, but I use split windows (`:sp` or `:vsp`) for that purpose.